# Problem with listing files on ftp/wget on SCO 5.07

Tags: ftp

Our system SCO OpenServer SCO_SV 3.2v5.0.7.

1. ftp "ls -l" command return listing without "user" column(like usual "ls -lg")
2. wget also create ".listing" files without "user" column.

Is there some kind of setting in the system so that the listing of files in ftp/wget comes out in a normal form, with all the columns?

Comment: What system? The local system or the remote system? Are you aware that the listing is generated by the server? In any case, this is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: What system?  -- local and remote.

".listing" - generate wget for each downloaded directory.